# Sum by groups between 2 tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I, im trying to Sum by groups between 2 tables. Basically im trying to show only the Table 'Count' with each SUM() of Table 'MoneyMovements' group by 'Bank_code'. Is this possible?. I tryed with Left join (including the 'MoneyMovements'in 'Count'). but i dont understand how to separe the sum... Any suggestion?. Im using ACCESS 2007 in VB.NET

```
Table 'Count'
+----+--------------+
|Code|Bank          |
+----+--------------+
|1   |MACRO         |
+----+--------------+
|2   |Santender Rio |
+----+--------------+
|3   |Galicia       |
+----+--------------+

Table 'MoneyMovements'

+-----+--------------+
|Money|Bank_code     |
+-----+--------------+
|200  |1             |
+-----+--------------+
|300  |1             |
+-----+--------------+
|0    |2             |
+-----+--------------+
|500  |3             |
+-----+--------------+
|100  |3             |
+-----+--------------+

Response i Want:
+-----+--------------+
|Money|Bank          |
+-----+--------------+
|500  |MACRO         |
+-----+--------------+
|0    |Santender Rio |
+-----+--------------+
|600  |Galicia       |
+-----+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `join` with `group by` like:

```
Select c.Code, sum(m.Money) as Money
From Count c
inner join MoneyMovements m on c.Code = m.Bank_code
group by c.Code
```

Comment: I All after hours and hours i find it! this is:

`"select p.Code,(SELECT SUM(b.Money) FROM MoneyMovements b WHERE b.Bank_code = p.Code) as SUM_TOTAL from 

Count p"`

Comment: Its works your code! i replace "inner join" by "Left join" to get all the  table "Count" rows. Now, how to display a 0 when are no transactions in that acount?

Answer (score 0):

Use "Left join" to get all the "Count" rows and **Nz()** to display 0 when there are no transactions in an account:

```
Select c.Code, Nz(sum(m.Money),0) as Money
From Count c
LEFT JOIN MoneyMovements m on c.Code = m.Bank_code
group by c.Code
```

---

Access really didn't like the table name "Count" so I used `Counts` instead, this is what I did:

[image]

```
SELECT Counts.code, Nz(Sum(MoneyMovements.Money),0) AS SumOfMoney
FROM Counts LEFT JOIN MoneyMovements ON Counts.Code = MoneyMovements.bank_code
GROUP BY Counts.code;
```

[image]

Comment: its strange... this return me anything... This Works: 'select c.Bank,(SELECT SUM(m.Money) FROM MoneyMovements m WHERE m.Bank_code = c.Code) as Total_money from Count c' Why this works and your not? im confused. first time i wrote something like you but doesnt work, after 6 hours i tried this way. therefore i tryed "Nz" function in my code but doesnt work. I use Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 and VB.NET

Comment: @RobertoPeña please note I added to my answer with an example built in Access